# char* gets corrupted on the final iteration of a loop

Tags: c, split, c-strings, string-literals, function-definition

So, I'm trying to build a `string_split` function to split a c-style string based on a delimiter.

Here is the code for the function:

```
char** string_split(char* input, char delim)
{
    char** split_strings = malloc(sizeof(char*));
    char* charPtr;

    size_t split_idx = 0;
    int extend = 0;

    for(charPtr = input; *charPtr != '\0'; ++charPtr)
    {
        if(*charPtr == delim || *(charPtr+1) == '\0')
        {
            if(*(charPtr+1) == '\0') extend = 1; //extend the range by one for the null byte at the end
            char* string_element = calloc(1, sizeof(char));

            for(size_t i = 0; input != charPtr+extend; ++input, ++i)
            {
                if(string_element[i] == '\0')
                {
                    //allocate another char and add a null byte to the end
                    string_element = realloc(string_element, sizeof(char) * (sizeof(string_element)/sizeof(char) + 1));
                    string_element[i+1] = '\0';
                }
                string_element[i] = *input;
            }
            printf("string elem: %s\n", string_element);
            split_strings[split_idx++] = string_element;
            
            //allocate another c-string if we're not at the end of the input
            split_strings = realloc(split_strings, sizeof(char*) *(sizeof(split_strings)/sizeof(char*) + 1));    

            //skip over the delimiter 
            input++;
            extend = 0;
        }
    }
    free(charPtr);
    free(input);
    return split_strings;
}
```

Essentially, the way it works is that there are two `char*`, `input` and `charPtr`.  `charPtr` counts up from the start of the input string the the next instance of the delimiter, then `input` counts from the previous instance of  the delimiter (or the start of the input string), and copies each `char` into a new `char*`. once the string is built it is added to a `char**` array.

There are also some twiddly bits for skipping over delimiters and dealing with the end points of the input string. the function is used as so:

```
int main()
{
    char* str = "mon,tue,wed,thur,fri";
    char delim = ',';
    char** split = string_split(str, delim);

    return 1;
}
```

Anyway, it works for the most part, except the first `char*` in the returned `char**` array is corrupted, and is just occupied by random junk.

For example printing the elements of `split` from `main` yields:

```
split: α↨▓
split: tue
split: wed
split: thur
split: fri
```

Whats odd is that the contents of `split_strings[0]`, the array of `char*` which returns the desired tokens is `mon`, as it should be for this example, right up until the final loop of the main for-loop in the `string_split` function, specifically its the line:

`split_strings[split_idx++] = string_element;`

which turns its contents from `mon` to Junk. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: `sizeof(string_element)` is just the size of a pointer, it's not the size of the memory it points to.

Comment: You're not increasing the sizes of the `string_element` and `split_string` arrays when you call `realloc()`.

Comment: @Barmar so I suppose I can use `strlen` for the `string_element`, but how would I extend the size of `split_strings`, by one `char*` ? Thanks for the note so far.

Comment: @jf192210 It is unclear what the function shall return: either just  positions of substrings or copies of substrings separated by the delimiter.

Comment: You should use a variable to hold the current allocation of each pointer. Then increment that variable and use it in `realloc()`.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow  suppose the input was as seen in `main` it should return a `char**` with elements "mon" "tue" "wed" "thur" "fri", with all the delimiters removed.

Comment: @Barmar That was a good solution thank you.

Comment: Doing `free(charPtr);` at the end is incorrect. Just do the `free(input);`. `charPtr` is _incremented_, so, at the end, it is _not_ pointing to a valid heap area [that _can_ be freed]. And, even if it were _not_ incremented, it would cause a "double free" abort from `free`

Comment: @CraigEstey Thanks for the advice Craig.

Comment: @CraigEstey `free(input);` is wrong.  From the example in the question, `input` comes from `char* str = "mon,tue,wed,thur,fri";`.  Calling `free()` on that pointer is undefined behavior that will almost certainly result in memory corruption and likely cause the process to crash some time in the future.  Since the `char** string_split(char* input, char delim)` function has no way to tell where the `input` pointer comes from, it can not safely `free()` it.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Thanks. I didn't look at `main`, so I assumed it did an alloc. I was considering a followup that would have said that _caller_ should do the `free` [if it _did_ an alloc] but since this wasn't OP's primary issue, I was going to loop back later.

Answer (score 0):

The final function for anyone wonder, should be pretty fool proof.

```
char** string_split(char* input, char delim, bool skip_delim)
{
    assert(*input != '\0');

    char** split_strings = malloc(sizeof(char*));
    char* charPtr;

    size_t split_idx             = 0;
    size_t num_allocated_strings = 1;
    size_t extend                = 0;

    for(charPtr = input; *charPtr != '\0'; ++charPtr)
    {
        if(*charPtr == delim || *(charPtr+1) == '\0')
        {
            if(*(charPtr+1) == '\0') extend = 1; //extend the range by one for the null byte at the end
            char* string_element = calloc(1, sizeof(char));

            for(size_t i = 0; input != charPtr+extend; ++input, ++i)
            {
            if(string_element[i] == '\0')
            {
                //allocate another char and add a null byte to the end
                char* temp = realloc(string_element, sizeof(char) * (strlen(string_element) + 1));
                if(temp == NULL)
                {
                    free(string_element);
                    free(split_strings);
                    break;
                }
                string_element = temp;
                string_element[i+1] = '\0';
            }
            string_element[i] = *input;
            }
            split_strings[split_idx++] = string_element;
            num_allocated_strings++;
            
            //allocate another c-string
            char** temp = realloc(split_strings, sizeof(char*) * num_allocated_strings);    
            if(temp == NULL)
            {
                free(string_element);
                free(split_strings);
                break;
            }
            split_strings = temp;

            //skip over the delimiter if required
            if(skip_delim) input++;
            extend = 0;
        }
    }
    split_strings[num_allocated_strings-1] = NULL;
    return split_strings;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function is incorrect at least because it tries to free the passed string

```
char** string_split(char* input, char delim)
{

    //...

    free(charPtr);
    free(input);
    return split_strings;
}
```

that in the case of your program is a string literal

```
char* str = "mon,tue,wed,thur,fri";
char delim = ',';
char** split = string_split(str, delim);
```

You may not free a string literal.

And the first parameter shall have the qualifier `const`.

There are numerous other errors in your function.

For example the expression `sizeof(string_element)/sizeof(char)` used in this statement

```
string_element = realloc(string_element, sizeof(char) * (sizeof(string_element)/sizeof(char) + 1));
```

does not yield the number of characters early allocated to the array pointed to by the pointer `string_element`. And there is no great sense to reallocate the array for each new character.

The function can look for example the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char ** string_split( const char *s, char delim )
{
    size_t n = 1;
    char **a = calloc( n, sizeof( char * ) );
    
    while ( *s )
    {
        const char *p = strchr( s, delim );
        
        if ( p == NULL ) p = s + strlen( s );
        
        if (  p != s )
        {
            char *t = malloc( p - s + 1 );
            
            if ( t != NULL ) 
            {
                memcpy( t, s, p - s );
                t[p-s] = '\0';
            }
            
            char **tmp = realloc( a, ( n + 1 ) * sizeof( char * ) );
            
            if ( tmp == NULL )
            {
                free( t );              
                break;
            }
            
            a = tmp;
            
            a[n-1] = t;
            a[n] = NULL;
            ++n;
        }
        
        s = p + ( *p != '\0' ); 
    }
    
    return a;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char* str = "mon,tue,wed,thur,fri";
    char delim = ',';

    char **split = string_split( str, delim );
    
    for ( char **p = split; *p != NULL; ++p )
    {
        puts( *p );
    }
    
    for ( char **p = split; *p != NULL; ++p ) free( *p );
    free( split );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
mon
tue
wed
thur
fri
```

Comment: Ok, maybe my use of `free` was wrong, but my function works fine apart from that. I shall implement the changes to `free`. I like your implementation too, but  its hard to understand with such short variable names personally.

Comment: @jf192210 Even your modified function is wrong. For example it returns uninitialized pointer char** split_strings = malloc(sizeof(char*)); in the case when the user passes an empty string.

Comment: @jf192210 Also the last pointer in the array pointed to by the pointer split_strings is not equal to NULL.

Comment: I suppose that would be a good idea to set it NULL. I have updated the response I made to this question, any chance you could check it out for errors?  Thank you.

Comment: @jf192210 I already wrote my answer to your question.:)  I have no time to return to the question periodically.:)

Comment: @jf192210 Your function has memory leaks.